# Execute SQL in multiple connections c#

Tags: c#, sql, connection

This is the Code i have and it works well when choose one connection string in Combobox

How can i execute same SQL query in multiple connections with one button click not one by one??

```
public string connstring = "";
        private void cmbSrv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbSrv.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                connstring = @"Data Source=tcp:10.1.0.100;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
            }
            else if (cmbSrv.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                connstring = @"Data Source=tcp:10.0.0.100;Initial Catalog=Database2 ;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";

            }
        }
private void btnKonfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring))

            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand command1 =
                    new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID="+textbox1+"", connection);                    



                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();


                connection.Close();
            }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some problems with your code like [**Sql Injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you can fixed with parameterized queries.

You are not taking the `Text` property of your `textbox1`. Fix your naming and don't use textbox1 for control names. Naming is important, so you can be understand by other programmers. Same is true for your database table, `Table1` is not appropriate name.

You don't need to `Close()` the connection when you are in `using` block. Using do this automatically. Also when you create an `SqlConnection` object you can open a connection, there is no need to make if checks about it.

```
public void ConfirmBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string connString1 = "FirstConnectionSTring";
     string connString2 = "SecondConnectionSTring";

     ExecuteNonQuery(connString1);
     ExecuteNonQuery(connString2);
}

public void ExecuteNonQuery(string connString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {

         connection.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd =
                    new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=@ID", connection);

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textbox1.Text);         

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexK. If you don't dispose SqlCommand you will not hurt yourself, there are no resources which should be handle by finalizer in the current implementation of the class. But yes it is a good practise to always Dispose IDisposable objects. One of the reasons is that the implementation can change in the future.

Comment: @AlexK. Also after research if you check the Constructor of SqlCommand in reference code you will see that he is calling `GC.SuppressFinalize(this); ` . [Reference Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,28d1b18c2d0a54c3)